# Custom node sockets and CustomSocketInterface in Blender Addon

Tags: python, sockets, nodes, blender

I'm using Blender 2.79 but Blender 2.8+ likely operates the same

[Example for custom nodes](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/release/scripts/templates_py/custom_nodes.py)

Initially, I was using NodeSocket subclasses as custom sockets, but eventually I got this error `AttributeError: 'NodeSocketInterface' object has no attribute 'draw_color'`. Others also had issues with `default_value` not being present in `NodeSocketInterface`.

How do I use this `NodeSocketInterface` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to not registering a `NodeSocketInterface`. When registering the `NodeSocket` subclass, a dummy `NodeSocketInterface` without the required methods/properties is [automatically created](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/1e4f6b231ce54e894b308c00e56525c085db8781/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_nodetree.c#L2143).

I wrote the following code based on understanding the Blender source code, and it works for registering a `CustomSocketInterface` associated to a `CustomSocket`:

```
# Blender 2.79
# (bl_idname defaults to class names if not set)

class CustomSocketInterface(bpy.types.NodeSocketInterface):
    bl_socket_idname = 'CustomSocket' # required, Blender will complain if it is missing
    # those are (at least) used under Interface in N-menu in
    # node editor when viewing a node group, for input and output sockets
    def draw(self, context, layout):
        pass
    def draw_color(self, context):
        return (0,1,1,1)

class CustomSocket(bpy.types.NodeSocket):
    def draw(self, context, layout, node, text):
        pass
    def draw_color(self, context, node):
        return (0,1,1,1)
...
# register (didn't try but order should matter)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomSocketInterface)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomSocket)
```